# Python: Using a variable previously used, inside of a while statement to create a loop until the variable is set to something required

Tags: python

Sorry about this guys. I have really gotten stuck here with something so simple and I am battling to find a solution. I am very new to python and would love some help from you guys!

I want to make a menu...for example.

Choose what you want to do by typing a number. Type 1 or 2...

[1.] Do this stuff...

[2.] Do that other stuff...

Here is what I wrote to keep asking for a new value if the input is not 1 or 2. In the code below I have excluded

```
x = input("Please type 1 or 2: ")

while x != 1:
     x = input("That was not a valid option. Try again: ")
```

I have come to find that the variable "x" is being created as a local variable inside the while loop. Is there a way where I can use the variable "x" globally? Sorry again for bothering you guys with such a bad question. I greatly appreciate any help given. Thanks!

Comment: `while x != '1'` input returns a string

Answer (score 3):

No, Python does not create local variables inside a loop.  It is because `input()` returns a *string* but you are comparing with an `int`: 1.

Either compare against a string:

```
while x != '1':
```

or convert the input to an integer:

```
x = int(input('Blah blah blah: '))
```

Python has no formal mechanism to create a variable beyond assignment.  Local variables are only created inside functions/methods, modules, classes and (in python 3) comprehensions.